# How do I make this working code validate, in this HTML file?

Tags: html, django

[Error generated by validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Gfe.gif)

The actual code looks like this in validator:

[Code as it appears in validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlYXR.gif)

Comment: This is not a working code. This is just an unescaped template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run validation on the generated source code, not from your working code. For example, open the page in a browser, right-click, and select 'view source code'